# Listar tag relacionada a uma Categoria Especifica Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Preciso listar os posts com determinada tag que pertença a uma categoria especifica. Já tentei todas as formas mas não deu certo.

Please!

```
<?php global $post; $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );?>
                <?php if(have_posts() ) : while(have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

                    <?php
                    global $post;
                    $args = array('tag' => 'editorial' );
                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

                <li>
                        <h3 class="categoria-h3"><a href="<?php the_Permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                        <p class="categoria-autor"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author', true); ?></p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true); ?>">PDF</a></button>

                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?> <?php endwhile; else:?> <?php endif;?> <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Leandro por favor tenta explicar melhor, não consegui entender o que você realmente precisa.

Comment: é o site de uma revista, cada edição é uma categoria. As edições são divididas em editoriais, que são os mesmos para todos as edições. Esses editoriais foram listados como tags. Preciso que as tags sejam listadas apenas da edição que esteja aberta para o usuário.